# Connecting SVN repository with its checkout that is many revisions older?

Tags: svn, merge, repository

I am solving a SVN based issue and would like to ask for help.
We use SVN to version one project, there is a central repository and every developer has his own checkout. If we develop, we then comit back to the central repository.
Our new colleague was afraid to comit to the repository so he wouldn't break it and he only made changes in his local checkouted folder (revision xxx1). He then for some reasons left the company and all the work he did was left in his local folder. The central repository is now 53 revisions ahead of his local checkout, but we need to get his work (he spent almost a month working on it) and somehow connect it to the repository.

Is there a normal, painless way to tell SVN "This is a folder with his work, show me what changes have been made in it in compare to revision xxx1", so I can solve conflicts, check his code and comit it?

It is not possible that I ask him to update and commit as he has no connection to us now and I can not use his account (deleted) to do the work. Only the checkouted folder is left on the drive.

I would be very grateful to get an advice here as it seems to me that noone on the interent has this problem.

Thanks in advance,
Jakub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand correctly everything.

I assume that:

1. You have working copy of repository (or at least you know revision number of his repository copy).
2. You cannot use this copy because is not connected to SVN server (no account) and you don't want to hack it.

If am right try:

1. Checkout project in revision number he last updated his repository -- you get *clean copy* of revision `xxxx`.
2. Copy files from his folder (omitting `.svn` folders) to folder with clean copy (created above) -- you get his modifications to revision `xxxx`.
3. Check if it works/compile.
4. Update repository to current version and resolve all conflicts.
5. Check if it still works/compile.
6. Commit changes -- should be done.

Good luck!

Comment: Yes, your assumption is right. I don't know why I didn't realize I could do it like that. Thank you!